# Performing and saving graphs from 96 well plates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with the time in the first column, and the rest of the columns correspond to fluorescence level for different wells(conditions), being ordered in this way: A01, B01, ... up to G12, H12 (typical 96 well plate).

I want to construct a script that build a graph for each well and save it in a .jpeg for example. I also want that the well name appear in the graph tittle. I show bellow what I have so far, but I get an error saying:
"Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function."

Any advice?
This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

rawdata <- read.csv2("xxxxxxx.csv")

Well_Name <- c("A01", "B01", "C01", "D01", "E01", "F01", "G01", "H01", "A02", "B02", "C02", "D02", "E02", "F02", "G02", "H02", "A03", "B03", "C03", "D03", "E03", "F03", "G03", "H03", "A04", "B04", "C04", "D04", "E04", "F04", "G04", "H04", "A05", "B05", "C05", "D05", "E05", "F05", "G05", "H05",  "A06", "B06", "C06", "D06", "E06", "F06", "G06", "H06",  "A07", "B07", "C07", "D07", "E07", "F07", "G07", "H07",  "A08", "B08", "C08", "D08", "E08", "F08", "G08", "H08",  "A09", "B09", "C09", "D09", "E09", "F09", "G09", "H09", "A10", "B10", "C10", "D10", "E10", "F10", "G10", "H10", "A11", "B11", "C11", "D11", "E11", "F11", "G11", "H11",  "A12", "B12", "C12", "D12", "E12", "F012", "G12", "H12")

for (i in Well_Name) {
  graph <- ggplot(rawdata[0:1600,],aes(x=time)) +  
    geom_line(aes(y=rawdata[,i], colour="black")) +
    labs(title = i, x = "time", y = "intensity")
  ggsave(paste(i,".jpeg", "", plot=graph))
}
```

Comment: I think you might have misplaced the parentheses at the `ggsave()` line.

Comment: @teunbrand, where can I see the correct configuration? I tried that, but I am new on this and didn´t find it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd want `ggsave(paste0(i, ".jpg), graph)`.

Comment: Thanks!
Now it says:
"Saving 7 x 7 in image
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1600): y, colour, x"
And creates one empty jpg named A01.
Another posibility could be to save all graphs in one pdf, showing the the well_name in the tittle.. but I don't how to do it.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what your data looks like and what shape it has, so I'm can't see how I'm supposed to debug that problem based on your error messages alone. `y=rawdata[,i]` doesn't seem typical ggplot2 code, but can't tell what exactly this is doing.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. My data is different levels of fluorescence in a 96-well plate. First column, time, rest of the columns: in the first row the well name, and in the rest the different values of fluorescence intensity along the time (first column). 
It seems I can not attach a picture to show it.
These are my column names:
time, A01, B01, C01, D01, E01, F01, G01, H01, A02, B02.....

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something along the following lines. This is just a rough guess based on your description of the data, so it may not work for you.

The important bit to change is probably `aes(y=rawdata[,i], colour = "black")` to `aes_string(y = i), colour = "black"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Making fake raw data, you can use your own
rawdata <- matrix(0, nrow = 1600, ncol = 96)
colnames(rawdata) <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(LETTERS[1:8], 1:12))
rawdata[] <- rnorm(length(rawdata))
rawdata <- as.data.frame(rawdata)
rawdata$time <- seq_len(nrow(rawdata))

# Don't include the time column as Well_Name
Well_Name <- setdiff(colnames(rawdata), "time")

# No need to select rows in the loop every time, we can do this just once
data <- rawdata[1:1600, ]

for (i in Well_Name) {
  graph <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time)) +
    geom_line(aes_string(y = i), colour = "black") +
    labs(title = i, x = "time", y = "intensity")
  # Ignore the tempdir() bit, this is for cleanup later
  # The code you should use in the comment line below:
  # ggsave(paste0(i, ".jpeg"), plot = graph)
  ggsave(paste0(tempdir(), "\\", i, ".jpeg"), plot = graph)
}

# Cleanup of tempdir, just so people that copy-paste this code won't end up
# with a tempdir bloated with jpeg pictures
files <- paste0(tempdir(), "\\", Well_Name, ".jpeg")
lapply(files, unlink)
```

Comment: Thank you for all the information and the effort. It didn´t work, something must be wrong or maybe the total script I did is not well written and it should be written in another way. thanks! Do you think it will be easier if I try to save them in a pdf file? the difficult part I think is making to take the tittle from the Well_name. 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: If this didn't work, then there is likely some part that I'm not understanding correctly.